# How do binary systems, such as computers, deal with decimal?

Tags: binary, decimal, computer-science

Although this question is not obviously related to a program, I think that it is quite interesting and it will help me with a program I am working on.

My question is this:

Computers are binary systems and have 3 fundamental operations available to them: AND, OR, and NOT (as I understand it), from which all of its other functions are derived. I can understand how the system can perform arithmetic on binary numbers using these operators, but how can the system then convert these numbers into decimal for the user without using the conventional operators (ie. +, -, *, /)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point is a starting point.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Binary_arithmetic Might help you understand the arithmetic. Though it might not go low-level enough as to explain what gates go into the operations, but sometimes you can find related articles that do.

Comment: As I said, I understand the arithmetic, just not how the system interprets this as decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

You have [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) or [IEEE Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) to deal with decimal in the binary system, there are other specifications, but these are the most common and the IEEE is the one computers use nowadays i think.